# URL Query Param Valid Syntax

Tags: url

Is it safe to use a URL like the following, where there is an ampersand right after the question mark?

http://address.com?&html=true&preview=true

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; that should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, however removing it is not hard and makes the URL prettier.

Comment: Thanks.  I know it's not hard.  I'm just working in a very limited embedded environment, and trying to limit any extra processing.

Comment: Ok, anyway it's safe so you can do it this way if you want.